# Jquery multiple selection options with output

Tags: jquery, select, output

I have no real idea what the name is for what I'm after so have struggled to find any help on it.

Im creating a selection tool on a website where the user is offered 3 types of customisations to a product, each of the three custimisations has 2 to 4 options.

I want the user to be able to click on one option from each of the 3 customisations, click 'go' and then get the relevant output as text(or a css class applied to a div).

I'm fine with creating the 3 sets of customisations allowing only one of the options to be the active state i each.

How do I go about checking which of the 3 customisations have been chosen and present the relevant output? Any help in the right direction would be most appreciated...

Comment: What you are looking for is called "radio buttons":  "allows the user to choose only one of a predefined set of options"

Comment: But I'd need 3 sets of radio buttons then a different output after all 3 sets have been answered...

Comment: Yes. you would need 3 sets.